# python sqlite3 execute multiple select queries

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table called **profil** parent table of **academic** and **projet** and am tryin to loop through all profils and get their academic and projet

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("Desktop/Dev/ScoutIT/src/db.sqlite3")
cur = conn.cursor()
candidats_id = cur.execute("select id from Candidat_profil ;")
for candidat_id in candidats_id: 
    academic= cur.execute('select * from Candidat_academic where profil_id = ?' , candidat_id)
    projet= cur.execute('select * from Candidat_projet_realise where profil_id = ?' , candidat_id)
    for row in academic:
        print(row)
    for row in projet:
        print(row)
```

the code above only print out projet but when i comment out projet i get academic printed .

**Note:**
**i have more child tables i want to implement in this code**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to chagne your code to the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3    
conn = sqlite3.connect("Desktop/Dev/ScoutIT/src/db.sqlite3")
cur = conn.cursor()
candidats_id = cur.execute("select id from Candidat_profil ;")
for candidat_id in candidats_id: 
    cur.execute('select * from Candidat_academic where profil_id = ?' , candidat_id)
    academic=cur.fetchall()
    cur.execute('select * from Candidat_projet_realise where profil_id = ?' , candidat_id)
    projet= cur.fetchall()
    for row in academic:
        print(row)
    for row in projet:
        print(row)
```

I advice you to use `cur.fetchone()` or `cur.fetchall()` for the documentation, feel free to visit : [a](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)